# MS-SQL index not using all the available columns as seek predicates

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server query on a large table (>17 million rows) that sometimes does not populate all the predicates before performing an index seek, which results in not filtering out enough rows and slowing the query down significantly (hours).

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database is used and this SQL query is generated by Hibernate.

Here is how the simplified query looks like:

```
SELECT MAIN_TABLE.FIELD_1,
       MAIN_TABLE.FIELD_2,
       MAIN_TABLE.FIELD_3,
       MAIN_TABLE.FIELD_4,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_1,
       TABLE_1.FIELD_2,
       TABLE_2.FIELD_1,
       TABLE_2.FIELD_2,
       TABLE_3.FIELD_1
FROM MAIN_TABLE
     INNER JOIN TABLE_1 ON MAIN_TABLE.TABLE_1_ID = TABLE_1.ID
     INNER JOIN TABLE_2 ON MAIN_TABLE.TABLE_2_ID = TABLE_2.ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_3 ON MAIN_TABLE.TABLE_3_ID = TABLE_3.ID
WHERE MAIN_TABLE.SOME_ID IN (SELECT SOME_ID FROM PARTITION_VIEW 
                             WHERE PARTITION_VIEW.SOME_FIELD_1 = [VALUE_1]
                             AND PARTITION_VIEW.SOME_FIELD_2 = [VALUE_2]
                             AND PARTITION_VIEW.SOME_FIELD_3 = [VALUE_3])
AND MAIN_TABLE.DATE BETWEEN [DATE_RANGE_1] AND [DATE_RANGE_2]
AND TABLE_1.STATE = [STATE]
```

The PARTITION_VIEW is a UNION of materialized views that all have index on columns  SOME_FIELD_1, SOME_FIELD_2, and SOME_FIELD_3.

In the `MAIN_TABLE`, we have an index on columns `DATE` and `SOME_ID` and this is the index that gets utilized which is correct.

When I checked the query plan from the SQL Server Management Studio, I found that in some cases such as when the date range is large (one year), the predicate used is the `DATE` column only. Then only after all the rows are within the given date range are found, the result set is filtered out by the given `SOME_IDs`.

It seems like the query optimizer did not pick the best query plan available.

When the exact query is directly executed from SQL Server Management Studio, everything performs correctly. This suboptimal query plan is used only when the query is executed from the application through Hibernate.

One thing I tried was to create actual table `PARTITION_TABLE` which copied over all the data from the `PARTITION_VIEW` and retrieved `SOME_IDs` from the `PARTITION_TABLE`, then the index on `MAIN_TABLE` was using all the predicates `(SOME_ID, DATE)`. I want to keep using the view if possible since it automatically reflects the changes.

Is it possible to keep using the union of materialized views and ensure that the index on the `MAIN_TABLE` will always retrieve the `SOME_ID` on the where clause first so that it can be used as part of the predicate in the index?

Comment: hello, how many rows you get form `SELECT SOME_ID FROM PARTITION_VIEW  
                             WHERE PARTITION_VIEW.SOME_FIELD_1 = [VALUE_1] 
                             AND PARTITION_VIEW.SOME_FIELD_2 = [VALUE_2] 
                             AND PARTITION_VIEW.SOME_FIELD_3 = [VALUE_3]` ?

Comment: PARTITION_VIEW estimates about 5000 rows where actual rows returned is couple hundreds at most, usually under 50. The PARTITION_TABLE estimates about 400 rows. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I think you should try an index on tuple (some_id, date) in this order.

Comment: Could you please explain why the index on tuple (date, some_id) won't be used? Is it because the date predicate is a range, not a equality predicate?

Comment: hmmm... it is almost the same thing. Do you have an index on this tuple despite the order?

Comment: So I have two indexes, with tuple (date, some_id) and (some_id, date, another_id). Right now, (some_id, date, another_id) gets used. There is an order by clause which I did not include, which orders by date in ascending. The indexes that gets used is (some_id, date, another_id) which will need to sort after all data has been retrieved which becomes a costly operation when large date range is used.